# profile missing list of enabled apex classes and VF pages

Tags: profile, metadata

I'm developing a managed package and I have a test EE org provisioned from the partner portal. I made an update to a profile there and when I pulled down the latest metadata all of my apex class and VF page permissions were gone.

Is this something new? Where is this info stored if not in the profile? I double checked the profile in SF and all of the Class/VF permissions are still there when viewing the profile in SF just not in the metadata.

Comment: I think Profile XML is somewhat dynamic. It pulls info about class/page permissions only if you pull them too (same for cust. objects). Can you post (maybe bit redacted) your package.xml?

Comment: Yes i think this is the case, you need to pull down the pages and objects in the same request. I also found a note in the metadata api about this working for managed only from API 29.0, so it may also depend on what version (and thus what tool) your using. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_profile.htm.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett and eyescream thats what it was! I was only requesting the latest for the .profile, once I added a .object or .page it was including the relevant XML. Seems pretty odd to me but thats how it works. Thanks!

Comment: @eyescream Want to do the honours? :)

Comment: Bah ;) Phil, make your own answer & accept, I'll happily throw the +1 there.

Comment: haha ok can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Profile XML is dynamic.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_profile.htm

> "The content of a profile returned by Metadata API depends on the
>   content requested in the RetrieveRequest message. For example,
>   profiles only include field-level security for fields included in
>   custom objects returned in the same RetrieveRequest as the profiles."

Ex. just doing a refresh from server(`RetrieveRequest`) in Eclipse or MM on the `.profile` file results in only high level details being returned. If you also include a `.object` in the request the Profile will include the details relevant to that object as well.

Comment: It's also worth noting that objects behave the same way.  They only retrieve what you ask them to retrieve.  Pulling a customfield will pull very basic xml for the object and then your custom field(s).